# what's difference between these

Tags: laravel, orm, relation

What's the difrence between these  ?

```
return $this->belongsToMany('Acme\Models\User','friends','user_id','friend_id');
```

and

```
return $this->belongsToMany('Acme\Models\User','friends','friend_id','user_id');
```

could someone explain it with sql ?

Comment: Why not print the query and explore yourself ?

Comment: how can i print query ? ->toSql() dosent work

Comment: Just QueryLog like this `$queries = DB::getQueryLog();
$last_query = end($queries);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The third argument is the foreign key name of the model on which you
>   are defining the relationship, while the fourth argument is the
>   foreign key name of the model that you are joining to.

In the **User model** you should use:

```
return $this->belongsToMany('Acme\Models\Friend','friends','friend_id','user_id');
```

And in the **Friend model**:

```
return $this->belongsToMany('Acme\Models\User','friends','user_id','friend_id');
```